# How to disable the Auto focus on UIImagePicker and works same as front Camera?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i want to Disable the Auto focus on a Camera Application Using UIImagePicker,and Works same as Front Camera without Focusing.Can anyone Help me in this?

i have used this code but only the  Square box is hidden, but still focusing...

```
-(void)disableAutoFocus
     {
         NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
         NSError *error;
         for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
             if (([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) &&
                ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) ) {
                 [device lockForConfiguration:&error];
                      if ([device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeLocked]) {
                          device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeLocked;
                          NSLog(@"Focus locked");
        }

        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can someone Help me in this plzz...?

Comment: Does anyone know how to implement a watermark in a UImagePicker Camera??